# Scala equivalent of Haskel Number

Tags: scala, typeclass

this might has been asked before, I have found some old answeres, but I find it hard to accept them.

I am trying to write a function that takes to numbers and adds them together:

```
object Add {
    def[A](a1: A, a2: A) = a1 + a2
}
```

and I get the error:

```
[error]  found   : A
[error]  required: String
```

Now obviously scala doesnt have Hindley-Milner type inference but you would expect there to be some abstract class, say `Number`, with all the base operations. If there is I cant find it. 
Instead I found out I am supposed to use type classes:

```
def add[A](a1: A, a2: A)(implicit n: Numeric[A]) = {
    a1 + a2
}
```

Doesn't work... but:

```
def add[A](a1: A, a2: A)(implicit n: Numeric[A]) = {
    import n._
    a1 + a2
}
```

Does, now this doesn't seem particularly clean to me. Please tell me there is a better way!

Not even regular type class use like;

```
def add[A: Numeric](a1: A, a2: A) = {
    a1 + a2
}
```

works, instead I have to add 2 lines:

```
def add[A: Numeric](a1: A, a2: A) = {
    val n = implicitly[Numeric[A]]
    import n._
    a1 + a2
}
```

I feeling like I am missing something fundamental here cause it shouldn't be this hard adding two numbers

**Update:**

Thanks to the answers I figured out it was possible to do the following:

```
import scala.math.Numeric._
import scala.math.Numeric.Implicits._

def add[A: Numeric](a1: A, a2: A) = {
    a1 + a2
}
```

Which is really what I wanted to do all along.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you require evidence that `A` is numeric, that evidence knows how to act upon elements of type `A`.

```
def add[A](a1: A, a2: A)(implicit ev: Numeric[A]) = {
  ev.plus(a1,a2)
}
```

Extra implicits are required to employ the more complicated infix notation.

```
def add[A](a1: A, a2: A)(implicit ev: Numeric[A]) = {
  import Numeric.Implicits._
  a1 + a2
}
```

---

> Not even regular type class use ...

It should be noted that what you call "regular type class use"

```
def add[A: Numeric](a1: A, a2: A) = {...
```

... is actually rewritten by the compiler into something like this ...

```
def add[A](a1: A, a2: A)(implicit evidence$1 Numeric[A]) = {...
```

... except that the compiler isn't constrained to any specific name mangling formula so you can't rely on the implicit parameter having a predictable name. Thus `implicitly` is used to re-materialize the implicit parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I guess my problem was that I missed the Implicits object on Numerics companion and thought I needed to import implicit ops from the evidence inside the function, which felt weird since I wanted it in a recursive function

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Numeric type-class method plus directly

```
def add[A](a1: A, a2: A)(implicit n: Numeric[A]) = {
    n.plus(a1,a2)
}
```

or

```
def add[A: Numeric](a1: A, a2: A) = {
  implicitly[Numeric[A]].plus(a1,a2)
}
```

In order to use the infix operator, you need an implicit in scope to convert the type A to a class with the appropriate method.  This is why we need to import the implicts provided by the type-class.